# Count img banner clicks with users GA account ID?

Tags: analytics

My clients would like to track the banner clicks in a a href tags. They have gif images on my page that after click redirect to their page. How can I adjust the code, so they can count the click with their GA account. Is this possible at all or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client specifically wants to track clicks on a banner image/gif on your page that redirects to his own, you could set up an intermediary redirect.

What I mean is to set up a profile on Google Analytics called "MyClient Image Banner Click" or something, then create a page on your server called clientClick.html and make it look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE FOR "MyClient Image Banner Click" PROFILE HERE */
</script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.customer.com/page.html">
</head></html>
```

Then, you have the image banner gif on your page redirect to clientClick.html instead of his site. This way, the only time this specific analytics code is triggered is when a user clicks on the image banner. After 0 seconds, this clientClick.html page will automagically redirect the user who clicked on the image to the actual destination page on your client's site. Your client gets to see all the user demographics right there in Analytics in his account.

This practice is a lot more common than you think. Think of all the times you have seen ads referencing an "out.php?id=blahblah&client=44" as the href? Hope this helps! Aloha. :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. :) Pay it forward when you learn something. :)